# Login with Curl on this website

Tags: php, curl

I try to log on [this website](http://www.grossiste-informatique.com) with curl but I got a problem (or much more) nothing happen, I don't get any data...

```
$urlRef ='grossiste-informatique.com/grossiste/detail_article_popup.php?code_article='. $s['reference'];

$urlLogin = 'grossiste-informatique.com/grossiste/auth_process.php';

$username = 'xxxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxxx';

$ch = curl_init($urlRef);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

$cl = utf8_encode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Comment: try to be more "human" provide browser and OS and then check what happens you can use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');`

Comment: i got this Warning: fopen(/home/www/src_sites/connexion.log) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/www/src_sites/sources_grossiste/snx_session.php on line 117

Comment: wait.. you want open file with curl which is on localpath? :) I don't understand why you need curl for it. I suggest reading what CURL is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(programming_language)

Comment: I try to connect to this website with curl for getting information, i've done without authentification, but i must get some information when u r logged.

Comment: here my curl 

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.grossiste-informatique.com/grossiste/auth_process.php');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login=xxxxxx&mdp=xxxxxx");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt');
   $testreturn = curl_exec($ch);